# Git hints about commits in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio

In the IDE, for every line I press, I get a grey hint next to it that tells me about the line - when it is committed. The hint is like *`You, 10 minutes ago • Uncommitted changes`*

How to disable those Git hints? It's driving me crazy

Answer (score 2):

In VSC I know there's a current line blame from [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) that you can disable that does the same thing.

[image: gitLens blame]

Android studio has a package extension called [GitToolbox](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox) with this function.

[image: gitoollbox]

You can disable and maintain only on your status bar.

[image]